# How to get only the newest entries with the same id in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have the following:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));

DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 3, 1, 7, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2007, 3, 1, 7, 0, 0);
DateTime date3 = new DateTime(2006, 3, 1, 7, 0, 0);

table.Rows.Add("123", date1);
table.Rows.Add("123", date2);
table.Rows.Add("ABC", date3);
```

I want to run an action which will delete all the rows which have the same id as another row and keep only the one with the newest date.

In this small example at the beginning I have:

```
123 2008...
123 2007...
ABC 2006...
```

After the action it should be:

```
123 2008...
ABC 2006...
```

How can I realize this?

(this is only a small example my real data is much bigger)

Comment: Where your data comes from? Are you using SQL Server? You can have that result using sql query then after that bind it to your datatable..

Comment: I upvoted this Question as well..Why don't you mark SirViver's answer as a solution? In my case, it's working excellently..Thank you for this question !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can't filter the data at the data source directly (= adjust the SQL query), you can delete the rows using the following code:

```
var multiDates = from dr in table.AsEnumerable()
                 group dr by dr.Field<string>("id") into grp
                 where grp.Count() > 1
                 select grp.OrderByDescending(gr => gr.Field<DateTime>("date"));

var toDelete = multiDates
    .SelectMany(rows => rows.Skip(1))
    .ToArray();

foreach (var row in toDelete)
    row.Delete();

table.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: My way was walking around around around with 3~ 4 loop..but this works with no possibility of mistake..It is exactly as being written..I want to up +10 vote for this excellent solution ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

In case you wish to check after you inserted all data you may sort your DataTable data by using a DataView, enumerate through any rows, check for duplicates and remove them..

```
DataView dv = new DataView(DATA_TABLE, "", "ID, Date DESC", DataViewRowState.None);
for (int i = 1; i < dv.Count; i++)
{
    if (dv[i - 1].Row["ID"] == dv[i].Row["ID"])
    {
       dv[i].Delete();
       i--;
    }
 }
```

In case you can check on insert, use some kind of e.g EndEdit_Event to check for duplicate IDs

You may even consider using some kind of dataSource (ArrayList, List, DataSet aso) and make use of constraints or some businessLogic check.

Comment: Your solution won't delete the rows with the oldest date, though ;)

Comment: this would require that all the id's are sorted, but they aren't.

Comment: that's why I sort them by using the dataView

Answer (score 0):

Here is one alternative

```
 var rowsToDelete = 
              (from outer in table.AsEnumerable()
              where !(from inner in table.AsEnumerable()
                    group inner by inner.Field<string>("id") into grp
                    where grp.Key == outer.Field<string>("id") &&
                          grp.Max (g => g.Field<DateTime>("date")) == outer.Field<DateTime>("date")
                    select grp.Key).Any()
              select outer).ToList();

foreach (var row in rowsToDelete) 
   row.Delete();
table.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Note that this will, if I'm not mistaken, throw an `InvalidOperationException` on deleting due to the modification of the underlying `DataTable` while enumerating through it. You have to force the immediate execution of the LINQ query by, for example, putting the result (the rows) in an array via `ToArray()` to allow deleting them from the table.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a linq query for distinct field ID like the below

```
var MyQry=(from P5 in table.AsEnumerable() select P5["id"]).Distinct().ToList();
for (int O1 = 0; O1 < MyQry.Count; O1++)
{
     richTextBox1.Text = MyQry[O1].ToString();
}
```